# Ruby on Rails require doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It's my first RoR application.

I want to use this class (app/models/from_db/users/user_base.rb)

```
module FromDb::Users
  class UserBase
      include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON

      attr_accessor :Login, :Email
 end
end
```

In this controller (app/controllers/my_controller.rb)

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  require "from_db/users/user_base"

  def default
    user = UserBase.new
    user.Login = "Marcin"
    user.Email = "ja@gmail.com"
  end
end
```

user = UserBase.new throw this error:

> uninitialized constant MyController::UserBase

When I put FromDb::Users::UserBase.new everything works fine but I thought that 'require' is like 'using' in C# or 'import' in java. I don't want to have to put this namespace all time before class from other dir. What I am doing wrong?

My second question. Is any way to write **require "FromDb/Users/UserBase"** instand of **require "from_db/users/user_base"** ? Now when I put first version (FromDb/Users/UserBase) it throw that error:

> cannot load such file -- FromDb/Users/UserBase

I use ruby 2.1.5 and Rails 4.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `require` is similar to Java's `import`, it doesn't have any of the namespace manipulation stuff that `import` provides. If you *really* want to have shorter references, you'll need to create them yourself.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  UserBase = FromDb::Users::UserBase

  def default
    user = UserBase.new
    # ... etc
  end
end
```

Also, since this is a Rails application, you don't need the explicit call to `require` (and it's better if you leave it off). If you name everything following the standard conventions, Rails will `require` the file for you automatically, then reload it whenever the file changes. If you do a manual `require` you'll lose the autoreloading.

Comment: Thank you. It helps me to better understand Rails :) + Information about autoreloading is a nice tip

Answer (score 2):

With regards to the first question, try the following to import the namespace

```
include FromDb::Users
```

Don't use imports all over the place as they might cause conflicts within your class (see comment by apneadiving).

Or simply create an alias:

```
FUsers = FromDb::Users
FUsers::UserBase.new...
```

Comment: I wouldnt include a `module` for so called `shortcut` sake, you;d just pollute and duplicate methods and classes all over the place + danger of collisions

Answer (score 1):

`require`just loads file's content in memory, so you still have to use `FromDb::Users::UserBase` and I recommend it, its clearer.

You cant camelize the name: its is meant to be a file name.

You have to give the path from the root, its safer:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/from_db/users/user_base"
```

Notice you dont need `require` since you have your code in `/app`

---

in order to create a shortcut you could do:

```
def default
  user = user_base_class.new
end

def user_base_class
  ::FromDb::Users::UserBase
end
```

this way you dont create useless constant.